# Listbox OnSelectedIndexChanged doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, updatepanel, autopostback

I have a listbox inside my jquery dialog,

```
<div id="dialog">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:ListBox ID="lbxTitle" runat="server" style="width:400px;height:100px;" OnSelectedIndexChanged="lbxTitle_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem value="2" Text="abc" />
    <asp:ListItem value="3" Text="def" />
</asp:ListBox>
<br />
<fieldset>
    <asp:Label ID="lblContent" runat="server" style="height:200px;" />
</fieldset>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

And in the behind code, I have this function

```
protected void lbxTitle_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   lblContent.Text = "test";
}
```

I dont  put autopostback="true" because it will refresh the whole page, and close my dialog.

How to make it so that when user click item on the listbox, it will show "test" on the label inside dialog.

Now, it doesnt do anything if I change the selected item.

Comment: It doesn't refresh the whole page but only the content of the `UpdatePanel`. An asynchronous postback is always still a full postback.

Comment: See if my answer resolves this for you.

Comment: I tried to put `autopostback` but it does refresh the whole page still even though I have `listbox` inside `updatePanel`. @TimSchmelter

Comment: @Bee: what means "it refrshes the whole page"?

Comment: `listbox` is inside a pop up dialog box which will appear when the button is clicked, when I set `autopostback` ="true", The page is refreshed and I have to click the button again to show dialog box. is it possible to not refresh the page but only change the value inside the dialog box? @TimSchmelter

Answer (score 1):

You should put the Autopostback then you can use AsyncPostBack to prevent whole page postback...

As per the following Code

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:ListBox ID="lbxTitle" runat="server" style="width:400px;height:100px;" OnSelectedIndexChanged="lbxTitle_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                <asp:ListItem value="2" Text="abc" />
                <asp:ListItem value="3" Text="def" />
            </asp:ListBox>
            <br />
            <fieldset><asp:Label ID="lblContent" runat="server" style="height:200px;" />
            </fieldset>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lbxTitle" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add AutoPostback and after you create your dialog move it back to the form:

```
$("#dialog").parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
```

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        <% if (Page.IsPostback) { %>
            $('id of your listbox').change();
        <% } %>
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Alright, now it called the function right, however it still refresh the whole page. Dialog is closed when the page refreshed. @thewisegod

Comment: See my modified code and see how that works for you.